# INSERTing triples in Marklogic with a SPARQL query via REST

Tags: sparql, marklogic

I have a Marklogic SPARQL endpoint available at url
http://data.mydomain.com:8910/v1/graphs/sparql

I entered this URL in my browser expecting a triple to be inserted in the database:

```
http://data.mydomain.com:8910/v1/graphs/sparql?query=INSERT%20DATA%20{%20GRAPH%20%3Chttp://data.foobar.corp/people%3E%20{%20%3Chttp://data.foobar.corp/x%3E%20%3Chttp://www.foobar.com/#ID%3E%20%22x%22%20.%20%20}%20}
```

Fyi, the query parameter, once decoded, looks like this:

```
INSERT DATA { GRAPH <http://data.foobar.corp/people> { <http://data.foobar.corp/x> <http://www.foobar.com/#ID> "x" .  } }
```

My endpoint returns this error message when I send the GET request above:

```
<error-response xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/error">
<status-code>400</status-code>
<status>Bad Request</status>
<message-code>XDMP-UNEXPECTED</message-code>
<message>XDMP-UNEXPECTED: (err:XPST0003) Unexpected token syntax error, unexpected INSERT DATA</message>
</error-response>
```

This query works fine in Virtuoso (another popular SPARQL endpoint).

Is it a normal behaviour? Should I check my server configuration?

Comment: Do you have write permissions on the marklogic endpoint?

Comment: Can you perhaps try adding double quotes around the parameter? These docs have quotes around the query - https://docs.marklogic.com/10.0/REST/GET/v1/graphs/sparql

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is legal : http://www.sparql.org/update-validator.html is an online checker (runs Apache Jena).

`?query=`

That is for queries - an update is not a query. SPARQL differentiates the two types of operation in the protocol.

Use `?update=` (and check that it is the update endpoint).